# How to click the visible: false button in capybara?

Tags: testing, rspec, automated-tests, capybara

I can able to get the element through

```
page.find_button("Save", visible: :hidden, wait: 5)
```

But i can't trigger a click

```
page.find_button("Save", visible: :hidden, wait: 5).click
```

Answer (score 2):

Because Capybara is primarily designed as a testing tool it attempts to emulate what a user could actually do.  Since a user can't click on a non-visible button Capybara can't directly either.  If you're testing you need to replicate what a user would do.

If, on the other hand, you're just automating a site to scrape some data and really want to trigger the click event you can try something like

```
page.find_button("Save", visible: :hidden, wait: 5).execute_script('this.click()')
```

Note: If you do that in code that is actually testing a site/app your test is basically worthless.